# Embedding a Java applet in a website using NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, applet

I'm creating a website in which I would like to add an applet. I have written the code for the applet in dr.java and the applet uses jar files from Jfreechart.  The problem occurs when I try to embed the applet inside the website which is in Netbeans HTML5 , most aspects of the applet program work fine but the aspects that come through the Jfreechart jar files don't work. I pretty sure that this is because the applet when copied to Netbeans doesn't carry the file paths to the jar files from Jfreechart. How do I add the file paths to those jar files in Netbeans.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vKeW.jpg)

In the image CreateGraphs,DataSet,Graph,PhsyicsGUI,Projectiles are all part of my applet program. PhyiscsGUI is the main method which runs the applet 
All these files share a file path to 2 jfreechart jar files which allow the graphing parts of the program.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaATB.jpg)

This image shows the result of the applet inside the website. The buttons that are seen create graphs when clicked but this fuction is not possible if the applet doesn't have file path to jar files. when i copied the java files from dr.java to netbeans I don't how to set the file path for the java files in netbeans.

Please help how do I set a file path for my java files which are embeded in a website ???

Comment: *"ow do I add the file paths to those jar files in Netbeans."*  The class path  cam be included in the manifest of the main Jar, or more 'reliable' (1) mention them in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` tag in the HTML. 1) Applets were never really reliable, and have become much less so in recent times.

Comment: *"Please help how do I set a file path for my java files which are embeded in a website ???"* Please fix that stuck `?` key.